# So I could So I can

Tags: grammar, tense

> 1) I chose to become a "**job**'' in the hopes of making  lots of money so I **could** buy a home. Why do you want to become a **''job''**?.
>
> 2) I chose to become a **''job''** in the hopes of making lots of money so I **can** buy a home. Why do you want to become a **''job''**  ?.

Which one is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is that you should use "can," but commentors will complain because I'm supporting the most-correct use of the verb in a poorly structured sentence.

So, one way to properly structure those sentences is (and I'm assuming some of your intent... I could be wrong):

> I chose my career with the hope of making enough money to buy a home.  Why did you choose your career?

An example of colloquial (spoken, not necessarily "book English") structure would be:

> I picked my job in the hope that I could buy a home.  Why did you pick your job?

As you can see, I did not use "can."

Comment: okey and why didn't you use can in your sentence  ' I picked my job in the hope that I could buy a home. Why did you pick your job? ' ?

Comment: Ah!  I should have noticed this when I answered.  Because the sentence is written in the past tense.  The verb "can" is present tense.  "I'm working this job in the hope that I can buy a home.  Why are you working your job?"

Comment: And I also failed to notice that you appear to be using "job" (with the quotes) as a placeholder.  In other words, "I chose to become an engineer with the hope that I could buy a home.  Why did you choose to become a doctor?"